# Display Images from raw data on web page

Tags: image, binary, jpeg

This question may have a simple answer and I may be asking it the wrong way.

I have a web application that pulls information from a server via an API (specifically librets and an MLS feed).  Part of the API returns images but in the form of raw binary data.

Currently I am writing this raw binary data to a .jpg file and storing them on my side for access later.  I was wondering if there was a way to display these images on a webpage using the raw data instead of having to save them on my side.

Comment: What do you mean by `raw binary data`? From where? What format? I mean a JPEG is binary? Do you mean the first byte is the top left red pixel, the second is the green and the third is the blue?

Comment: Basically I have a string that is the form '\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00`\x00`\x00\x00\xff\xe1\x00"Exif\x00\x00MM\x00...' etc. Currently I open a file called "foo.jpg" write to it then save it to a resource file on my side and access the file in the <img> src tag later to display on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I am equally unsure I am on the right track with an answer, so just kindly ignore or say, rather than downvote me if my interpretation of your querstion is `in the wrong way` like your question!

You can serve an image from PHP rather than from a file - I mean you can have PHP dynamically create an image and serve it rather than having to have a file in your webserver's filesystem and having to refer to it by name in the `src` field of an `<image>` tag in your HTML.

So, instead of

```
<image src="....jpg" alt="..." size="...">
```

you can use

```
<img src="/php/thumb.php?param1=$col&param2=$ref"/>
```

which causes the PHP script at `/php/thumb.php" to be called when the page is rendered. In that script, you can dynamically create the image (using extra parameters if you wish) like this:

```
<?php    
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$p1 = $_GET['param1'];
$p2 = $_GET['param2'];

$src = imagecreatefromstring(SOMESTRING);
$dst = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
imagecopyresampled($dst,$src,0,0,0,0,$width,$height,$size[0],$size[1]);
imagedestroy($src);
imagejpeg($dst);
imagedestroy($dst);
?>
```

I have omitted some code after the first 3 lines so you just see the technique rather than all the gory details of my code. The actual lines you are interested in are:

```
header(...image/jpeg);
```

which tells the browser what type of stuff is coming - i.e. an image, and

```
imagejpeg();
```

which actually sends the stream of JPEG data to the browser.