# How to manage different image sizes on a website

Tags: image, image-processing, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a website that is going to host thousands of images. Not only that, but each image has different size depending on where you are in the webpage - on the list page, the image is shown as 350x200 rectangle, on the sidebar pictures are 100x100 etc.

So when a user uploads an image to the website, I keep the original and make 4 resized copies for each size. So if 100 users upload an image, the result will be 500 images. I can't event think of what will happen with the different sizes of the different mobile devices...

I started using CloudFront to optimize speed. And when a user uploads an image I upload the original and the resized copies to Amazon S3 bucket. 
But if tomorrow I decide to add another size, or change an existing size I have to run a script that deletes the old sized images and to uplaod the newly sized images, which means "get the original from S3, resize it, upload the new size". That is not practical at all. Imagine when I do a complete redesign of the website and the image sizes change completely, I would have to run a script that resizes each image to the new requirements and to delete the old images.

Is there a more practical way to acheive that?

I wanted to acheive the following scenario:

- When the user uploads an image, I resize it and upload it to S3
- CloudFront will take the images which are directly resized
- When I add another size, I want CloudFront to see that this size is missing on S3 and pull it from an origin from my website.

I cannot think of a way to implement this. Any help or sharing best practices will be appretiated.

Comment: One option might be just to store the highest resolution image and then dynamically generate other sizes *"on-the-fly"*. I did a little PHP script that shows the sort of thing, except you would pass an image filename and the width and height as parameters and call one of PHP's `imagecopyresampled()` methods https://stackoverflow.com/a/25835507/2836621 . Another example https://stackoverflow.com/a/30573825/2836621

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I forgot to mention that I did exactly that (see my comment on the John Rotenstein's answer). If this is the only good solution, then I will leave it as it is. I just thought there is something that I cannot think of.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than doing all this yourself, you could use an **image resizing service** such as:

- [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/)
- [Imgix](http://imgix.com/)

They can resize images on-the-fly so you do not have to create and store them yourself. They can also manipulate them (rotate, watermark, colorize) images on-the-fly. Videos too!

If you choose not to use such a service, you could create your own virtual resizing service. The major choice is whether to:

- Resize on-the-fly (using CloudFront for caching but not requiring any storage of the resized images), or
- Resize upon request and store the result for future access (less processing cost, but involves storage cost)

It is *not* possible to have CloudFront "see that this size is missing on S3 and pull it from an origin from my website". (You might be able to do fancy stuff with 404 pages, but it wouldn't be worth the effort.)

Comment: Thank you for your response! What I already did is to use my server for a source and not S3. I don't upload all sizes to S3, just the original. Then when CloudFront doesn't have an image, it requests it from my server. I fetch the original from S3, resize the original, according to what CloudFront wants, and that's it. I don't like this approach, because when I first try to open an image later, there is some delay. After that CloudFront returns them directly and everything is extremely fast. Just that first time annoys me, but maybe that is the only solution.

Comment: Otherwise, I did a lot of research and found what you listed even before amazon, but it is expensive and sometimes you pay even if you don't use.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone doing this now. It's not for everyone, but due cost-saving efforts we just switched from Imgix to using AWS's [Serverless Image Handler](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/serverless-image-handler/). Works great if your images are on S3 and maybe a good alternative solution if it lacks the features of Imgix.